# Binding JSON string to ListView in Metro apps?

Tags: html, data-binding, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application(HTML5 & WinJS) in which am trying to display service data . Actually here am retrieving JSON data from my service but am unable to bind this data into listview . Anyone give me some working example.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "am unable to bind this data into listview"? Are you getting exceptions? Can you post the code where you are adding the JSON data into the required WinJS.Binding.list and wiring that up to the ListView control?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `WinJS.xhr()` for this. You can read more about it on this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx and here is an example:

```
var path = "data/file.json";
function getData(path) {
    WinJS.xhr({ url: path }).then(
        function (response) {
            var json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

            // Since this is an asynchronous function, you can't
            // return the data, so you can:
            // 1) retrieve the data to a namespace once the app loads.
            var list = new WinJS.Binding.List(json);
            Somenomespace.data = list;

            // 2) or do all the binding inside the function.
            var listView = document.getElementById("listViewID");
            listView.winControl.itemDataSource = list.dataSource;
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in JSON.parse(jsonString) function you can loop through the content using a normal for loop as it then is a normal object and add it as usuall. Just remember to process or render the data.

Her is an example from code i had in a search page using listview:

```
var response = JSON.parse(data) ; 
var originalResults = new WinJS.Binding.List();

for (x in response) {
    originalResults.push(response[x]); 
}

this.populateFilterBar(element, originalResults); 
this.applyFilter(this.filters[0], originalResults);
```

Comment: Hard to indent code on cellphone... Will fix when I am on a computer

Comment: @Thank you Sindre ,here populateFilterBar,applyFilter&filters means?those are id's of html elements?

Comment: Those are methods from the original search template provided by Microsoft. Basically they just run a WinJS.Binding.processAll if I am not mistaking